# Change laptop monitor aspect ratio

Tags: windows-7, resolution, aspect-ratio

I am trying to play Myst IV on my laptop in Windows 7 with a recommended resolution setting of 1920x1080. However, the game has a different aspect ratio, so everything is slightly "wider" than it should be. Is there any way to force either the program or windows to run with a different aspect ratio, displaying two vertical black bars on the left and right sides of my display? I've tried setting the compatibility settings to use "640x480" resolution but it still seems skewed. I noticed in the game's graphics menu, the largest setting is 1024x768, so I think that's the ratio I need. I could try a vm, but I don't have a windows install disk.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered I could change the scaling and aspect ratio in my graphics card (NVIDA) Control Panel.